# Channel creation fails due to nonexistent setting orderer.tls.clientKey.file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create a channel with a CLI container in Kubernetes. However, it fails with the following error message:
`Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.clientKey.file: open : no such file or directory command terminated with exit code 1`

I searched everywhere for a `orderer.tls.clientKey.file` setting - without success.

**Question:** Where should this setting be located?
I already tried it as environment variable at the CLI and at the orderer, also I introduced a new `orderer` section within the peer's `core.yaml` file - everything failed.

TLS, client authentication, NodeOUs are enabled (if that matters somehow).
HLF Version 2.1

Channel creation command:

```sh
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/config/admin/msp
peer channel create -c channel1 -f /config/peer/channel1.tx -o org1-orderer:30011 --outputBlock /channels/channel1.block --clientauth --tls --cafile /config/peer/tls-msp/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem
```

CLI env vars:

```yaml
env:
  - name: FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC
    value: grpc=debug
  - name: CORE_PEER_ID
    value: org1-cli
  - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
    value: org1-peer1:30151
  - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
    value: Org1MSP
  - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
    value: "true"
  - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
    value: /config/peer/tls-msp/tlscacert/ca-cert.pem
  - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED
    value: "true"
  - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE
    value: /config/peer/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem
  - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE
    value: /config/peer/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem
  - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
    value: /config/peer/msp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want [Mutual TLS](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-create), as in server and client authentication.  If that is the case, then (I think) you need the key file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint in two places:  the CLI environment variables like you have and in the create channel command itself.

- Try `--keyfile <Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key>` in the CLI command.

Comment: Thanks Rob! You were right! Additionally, I had to add `--certfile <Path>`.